# Multiple custom time formats in go for JSON Marshall

Tags: go, time, marshalling

I have a utility function for marshalling and unmarshalling custom time formats in go that is working fine for one format string and is used in a JSON model as follows

```
    type Entry struct {
        ID                int              `json:"id"`
        AuthorisedBy      string           `json:"authorisedBy"`
        Duid              string           `json:"duid"`
        IntervalCount     int32            `json:"intervalCount"`
        Intervals         []int32          `json:"intervals"`
        RequestId         string           `json:"requestId"`
        RequestTimestamp  time.Time        `json:"requestTimestamp"`
        TradingDate       utils.CustomTime `json:"tradingDate"`
        Unit              string           `json:"unit"`
        RebidExplanation  string           `json:"rebidexplanation"`
        AcceptedTimestamp time.Time        `json:"acceptedTimestamp"`
}
```

The utility function being.

```
package utils

import (
    "database/sql/driver"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time,
}

const ctLayout = "2006-01-02"

func (ct *CustomTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    s := strings.Trim(string(b), "\"")
    if s == "null" {
        ct.Time = time.Time{}
        return
    }
    ct.Time, err = time.Parse(ctLayout, s)
    return
}

func (ct *CustomTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if ct.Time.UnixNano() == nilTime {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", ct.Time.Format(ctLayout))), nil
}

var nilTime = (time.Time{}).UnixNano()

func (ct *CustomTime) IsSet() bool {
    return ct.UnixNano() != nilTime
}

func (c CustomTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return driver.Value(c.Time), nil
}

func (c *CustomTime) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch t := src.(type) {
    case time.Time:
        c.Time = t
        return nil
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("column type not supported")
    }
}
```

My issues, is that I now need to format one of the other fields with exactly 3ms fields such as ctLayout = "2006-01-02 15:04:05.000".

My question is, how do I set this up so I don't need to duplicate the entire structure, Is there a way I can pass in the ctLayout string in the Entry structure and pick it up in the utility function.  I'm sure there is, but I can't for the life of me work out how.

If I need to create a CustomTimeMS class, then so be it, but it seems like a lot of duplicate code.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva, can you please convert your comments into an answer... I created a new type with the new formatting, created a MarshalJSON and it seems to be working. Seems it could be a bit of whack a mole with lots of different fields, but works for this app anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

**One**

Add an exported field **CTLayout** to struct **Entry**

```
type Entry struct {
        ID                int              `json:"id"`
        AuthorisedBy      string           `json:"authorisedBy"`
        ...
        ...
        AcceptedTimestamp time.Time        `json:"acceptedTimestamp"`
        CTLayout          string           `json:"-"`
}
```

Update the **MarshalJSON** function

```
func (ct *CustomTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if ct.Time.UnixNano() == nilTime {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", ct.Time.Format(ct.CTLayout))), nil
}
```

Since **CTLayout** is exported it's accessible from anywhere.

Update **CTLayout** with what you need before calling `json.Marshal` on the CustomTime value

====================================

**Two**

Add an unexported field

```
type Entry struct {
        ID                int              `json:"id"`
        AuthorisedBy      string           `json:"authorisedBy"`
        ...
        ...
        AcceptedTimestamp time.Time        `json:"acceptedTimestamp"`
        ctLayout          string
}
```

update the **MarshalJSON** function

```
func (ct *CustomTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if ct.Time.UnixNano() == nilTime {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", ct.Time.Format(ct.ctLayout))), nil
}
```

create a exported helper marshal function

```
func (ct *CustomTime) Marshal(ctLayout string) ([]byte, error) {
        // You can do whatever else you want here
        // we'll do the obvious
        ct.ctLayout = ctLayout
        return ct.MarshalJSON()
}
```

call `ct.Marshal(your layout)`

If you have access to the package in which CustomTime exists go ahead and modify the CustomTime instance directly and make **Marshal** unexported if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an automatic way to pass information from `Entry` to `CustomTime`'s `MarshalJSON` method, not even using the struct tags. The only thing you can do, I believe, apart from creating a new type, is to add a new field to `CustomTime` and then, just before marshaling the `Entry` instance, *manually* set it to some value that will indicate how `MarshalJSON` should format the output. My suggestion would be to create a new type, a bit repetitive but cleaner.

Note that embedding allows you to avoid having to re-implement those methods that are supposed to behave the same in both, the embedded type and the embedding type. So, in your case, you only need to re-implement the json marshaling and unmarshaling methods. The isset, value, and scan methods don't have to be re-implemented.